# i3wm: How do I set real transparency for terminal with urxvt?

Tags: debian, i3, urxvt

i am using Debian 9.9 stretch and have installed i3 and urxvt.
I was able to make my console transparent but when I open a terminal and make it small so I can move it around, the transparent background is just updating slow and is not "real transparent"

[This is my ~/.Xdefaults file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPyjS.jpg)

Does anyone has a solution ? :)

Answer (score 1):

On my Debian I've added the sequent in the .Xresources:

```
! Setting transparency and background                                                                                                                                       
URxvt*depth:      32                                                                                                                                                        
URxvt.background: [85]#282828
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this (add the below to lines to the Xdefaults file):

```
urxvt*fading:           10

urxvt*fadeColor:        #000000
```

Answer (score 0):

add this into your .bashrc

```
#[ -n "$XTERM_VERSION" ] && transset --id "$WINDOWID" 0.7 >/dev/null
```

before you do this, please install **xtransset** and **xcompmgr**

It works for xterm. You may try it.

More detail please read [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Per-application_transparency)

Answer (score 0):

You must have a composite manager like `xcompgr` or `compton` installed on your system.

Then, you can add color transparency in:

```
URxvt.depth: 32
URxvt*background: rgba:0000/0000/0000/cccc
```

Be careful, the `URxvt.transparent` field must be `false`